# How to submit a form using PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, html, session

I have a simple HTML form on my site. I submit my form using a button. The button is a PNG, not a regular submit button, so until now, I have been using `onClick="document.getElementById("myFormId").submit();"` as an HTML property for my Submit-Image.

Now, I want to capture the values of 2 fields (Username and Password), so I decided to use sessions.

So I used this code before my HTML tags:

```
<?php
session_start();
$_SESSION["username_field"] = $username;
?>
```

But that stores the variable when the page loads, which will make $username = nothing.

Bottom Line:  I need to store this $_SESSION variable when the form submits. (And I would prefer to use $_SESSION, rather than others.)

Please tell me how to `$_SESSION["user"] = $userfield;` when the Image is clicked. Thank You.

Comment: `if(isset($userfield)){ ... }`

Comment: Please look up some tutorials on [forms and php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php).

Comment: What's wrong with using `<button>`?

Comment: are you using post or get method?

Comment: `if (!empty($_SESSION['username'])) { $_SESSION["username_field"] = $_POST['username'];`

Comment: You would be better off using the example I've given you above, which would save you from having to redeclare any POST elements. That way, if a session is set (or not empty), it will show the information. If the session is empty, then it won't show anything. That's the method I use.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to check if the value is set:

```
<?php
   session_start();
   if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
       $_SESSION["username_field"] = $_POST['username'];
   }
?>
```

If your form method is `method="GET"`, you have to replace the `$_POST` to `$_GET`.

Answer (score 0):

Forms either submit with `method="get"` or `method="post"` and then you access that data on the next page load with `$_GET` and `$_POST` respectively.

Look up some elementary tutorials: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp